# Cannot subscribe to PowerPacks.Shape.Click event

Tags: vb.net

Help on capturing a mouseclick for an OvalShape.

I have a form with a picturebox (myPictureBox).

When you click anywhere on myPictureBox, myPictureBox.click fires - OvalShape1 is drawn at that point.

When you click a second time, myPictureBox.click fires and OvalShape2 is drawn at that point.

...except if you click inside or on the border of OvalShape1.  Then OvalShape1 is selected and myPictureBox.click is not raised.

How do I capture the OvalShape1.Click event?

MSDN code not helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shape.click.aspx

B/C I get a :
*Error  BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.*

I am having hardtime figuring out how to add a handler to OvalShape1

Full code :

```
Public Class Form1

Public canvas As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer
Public OvalShape1, OvalShape2, OvalShape3 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  canvas.Parent = myPictureBox
  OvalShape1.Parent = canvas
  OvalShape2.Parent = canvas
  OvalShape3.Parent = canvas
 End Sub

 Private Sub myPictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myPictureBox.Click

 ..additional code to start drawing ovalshapes which works fine

 End Sub


Private Sub OvalShape1_Click() Handles OvalShape1.Click
  msgbox("you have cicked the OvalShape1")
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading as the event is not _not raised_, you just cannot subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get tells you exactly what's going on. Whenever you use the [**`Handles` clause**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) the variable of the event you are subscribing to must be declared as [**`WithEvents`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aty3352y.aspx).

Add that to your `OvalShape#` declaration and you should be good to go:

```
Public WithEvents OvalShape1, OvalShape2, OvalShape3 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape
```

On a side note, you should also include the event's parameters in your event handler method:

```
Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OvalShape1.Click
```

Comment: @user3208998 : Sometimes one misses what's right under one's nose :). If it solved your problem please mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on the left. Doing so will reward the answerer with 15 reputation point, and the asker 2 reputation points.